# Filter Custom List/ Document Library display via JQuery Rest Api

Tags: 2013, custom-list, filter, sharepoint-rest-api, content-editor-web-part

I tried using Api rest to filter the Custom list / Document Library display via jQuery , the script is working but the display of the list is not changing. Am i missing something? Thanks!

```
function Divsion()  
{  

    var Ownurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Benefits')/items?$select=*&$filter=Title eq 'HeatReports'";
    $.ajax({  

        url: Ownurl,  
        headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
        async:false,  
        success: function (data) {  

        },eror: function (data) {  
        alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
}  
    });  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it the out of the box list view?

Comment: Yes, Custom list and Document Library

Comment: Ok in that case you should use the View settings to filter. If you use jQuery method they you need to create the List View using HTML's

Comment: How can we do that? We need to filter 2 columns in the same time lets say get country from user profile country property and filter it by another field. thanks!